# How do I link the jQuery plugin in html document

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to link the *Social FloatingShare* jQuery plugin in HTML document. I have try to link this jQuery plugin, But calling the plugin function `floatingShare()` is not working as I excepted.

**I have two questions:**

1. How to link a jQuery in my html document?
2. What mistake I have done in my code?

**My Source Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Jquery Plugin</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #ccc; }
        .container { height: 500px; width: 1000px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("body").floatingShare();
        });
    </script>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.floating-share.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: created jsfiddel for you https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/gd0grwpt/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include jquery plugins before its use because all the jQuery or jQuery functions should be available before using, so change the jquery library and script sequence as show below -

**NOTE** - It is good practice to keep script tag directly into `<body>` or `<head>` tag instead of any other html element.

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.floating-share.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   $("body").floatingShare();
  });
</script> 
<div class="container"> 

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Include all `.js` files at the end of `Body` block is a good practice for loading performances. Then, you have to make sure call any JavaScript functions from your references after the page is fully loaded.

Two common options I usually choose:

***Option 1***. Include the jQuery library in `Head`, and keep all other `.js` files at the end of `Body` block. In your case, the JavaScript related part code should be as:

```
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("body").floatingShare();
                });
            </script> 
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.floating-share.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```

***Option 2***. Keep all `.js` files at the end of `Body` block, then implement `$(document).ready()` in JavaScript rather than using jQuery library. According to jQuery resource, the equivalent pure JavaScript implementation of `$(document).ready()` is:

```
    var ready = (function(){    

        var readyList,
            DOMContentLoaded,
            class2type = {};
            class2type["[object Boolean]"] = "boolean";
            class2type["[object Number]"] = "number";
            class2type["[object String]"] = "string";
            class2type["[object Function]"] = "function";
            class2type["[object Array]"] = "array";
            class2type["[object Date]"] = "date";
            class2type["[object RegExp]"] = "regexp";
            class2type["[object Object]"] = "object";

        var ReadyObj = {
            // Is the DOM ready to be used? Set to true once it occurs.
            isReady: false,
            // A counter to track how many items to wait for before
            // the ready event fires. See #6781
            readyWait: 1,
            // Hold (or release) the ready event
            holdReady: function( hold ) {
                if ( hold ) {
                    ReadyObj.readyWait++;
                } else {
                    ReadyObj.ready( true );
                }
            },
            // Handle when the DOM is ready
            ready: function( wait ) {
                // Either a released hold or an DOMready/load event and not yet ready
                if ( (wait === true && !--ReadyObj.readyWait) || (wait !== true && !ReadyObj.isReady) ) {
                    // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
                    if ( !document.body ) {
                        return setTimeout( ReadyObj.ready, 1 );
                    }

                    // Remember that the DOM is ready
                    ReadyObj.isReady = true;
                    // If a normal DOM Ready event fired, decrement, and wait if need be
                    if ( wait !== true && --ReadyObj.readyWait > 0 ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // If there are functions bound, to execute
                    readyList.resolveWith( document, [ ReadyObj ] );

                    // Trigger any bound ready events
                    //if ( ReadyObj.fn.trigger ) {
                    //  ReadyObj( document ).trigger( "ready" ).unbind( "ready" );
                    //}
                }
            },
            bindReady: function() {
                if ( readyList ) {
                    return;
                }
                readyList = ReadyObj._Deferred();

                // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
                // browser event has already occurred.
                if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
                    // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
                    return setTimeout( ReadyObj.ready, 1 );
                }

                // Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
                if ( document.addEventListener ) {
                    // Use the handy event callback
                    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );
                    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
                    window.addEventListener( "load", ReadyObj.ready, false );

                // If IE event model is used
                } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
                    // ensure firing before onload,
                    // maybe late but safe also for iframes
                    document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );

                    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
                    window.attachEvent( "onload", ReadyObj.ready );

                    // If IE and not a frame
                    // continually check to see if the document is ready
                    var toplevel = false;

                    try {
                        toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
                    } catch(e) {}

                    if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
                        doScrollCheck();
                    }
                }
            },
            _Deferred: function() {
                var // callbacks list
                    callbacks = [],
                    // stored [ context , args ]
                    fired,
                    // to avoid firing when already doing so
                    firing,
                    // flag to know if the deferred has been cancelled
                    cancelled,
                    // the deferred itself
                    deferred  = {

                        // done( f1, f2, ...)
                        done: function() {
                            if ( !cancelled ) {
                                var args = arguments,
                                    i,
                                    length,
                                    elem,
                                    type,
                                    _fired;
                                if ( fired ) {
                                    _fired = fired;
                                    fired = 0;
                                }
                                for ( i = 0, length = args.length; i < length; i++ ) {
                                    elem = args[ i ];
                                    type = ReadyObj.type( elem );
                                    if ( type === "array" ) {
                                        deferred.done.apply( deferred, elem );
                                    } else if ( type === "function" ) {
                                        callbacks.push( elem );
                                    }
                                }
                                if ( _fired ) {
                                    deferred.resolveWith( _fired[ 0 ], _fired[ 1 ] );
                                }
                            }
                            return this;
                        },

                        // resolve with given context and args
                        resolveWith: function( context, args ) {
                            if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) {
                                // make sure args are available (#8421)
                                args = args || [];
                                firing = 1;
                                try {
                                    while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
                                        callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );//shifts a callback, and applies it to document
                                    }
                                }
                                finally {
                                    fired = [ context, args ];
                                    firing = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            return this;
                        },

                        // resolve with this as context and given arguments
                        resolve: function() {
                            deferred.resolveWith( this, arguments );
                            return this;
                        },

                        // Has this deferred been resolved?
                        isResolved: function() {
                            return !!( firing || fired );
                        },

                        // Cancel
                        cancel: function() {
                            cancelled = 1;
                            callbacks = [];
                            return this;
                        }
                    };

                return deferred;
            },
            type: function( obj ) {
                return obj == null ?
                    String( obj ) :
                    class2type[ Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) ] || "object";
            }
        }
        // The DOM ready check for Internet Explorer
        function doScrollCheck() {
            if ( ReadyObj.isReady ) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                // If IE is used, use the trick by Diego Perini
                // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
                document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
            } catch(e) {
                setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 1 );
                return;
            }

            // and execute any waiting functions
            ReadyObj.ready();
        }
        // Cleanup functions for the document ready method
        if ( document.addEventListener ) {
            DOMContentLoaded = function() {
                document.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );
                ReadyObj.ready();
            };

        } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
            DOMContentLoaded = function() {
                // Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).
                if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
                    document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );
                    ReadyObj.ready();
                }
            };
        }
        function ready( fn ) {
            // Attach the listeners
            ReadyObj.bindReady();

            var type = ReadyObj.type( fn );

            // Add the callback
            readyList.done( fn );//readyList is result of _Deferred()
        }
        return ready;
        })();
```

Then, you can use it like:

```
    ready(function(){
      $("body").floatingShare(); // Assuming jQuery Lib has been included as well
    });
```

By far, I think option 1 should be more acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

In your code there is a code sequence issue. According to jQuery code Sequence, You have to include jQuery first in your document and then all your custom function as suggested by @Bhushan Kawadkar in above answer.

If you still want to add your function in body where you have added it then you can include jQuery in `<head>` of document e.g

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Horizontal-Floating-Social-Share-Bar/js/jquery.floating-share.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container"> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("body").floatingShare();
});
</script> 
</div>
</body>
```

And You plugin will start working.

Somehow it is recommended to add scripts(js) in footer to improve render times of your page.

Here is a live demo for you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AIEnl

Comment: Dear @Jamil I'm new on **stackoverflow**, I can't find the option where I select this is _accepted_ :( If you help **reference** so share the link in comment and again advanced thanks for helping :) :)

Comment: @JamilAhmad Thanks :)